# Prove an inequality by a convexity argument

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the inequality $|x^{2k-1} -y^{2k-1}|\leq \frac{2k-1}{2}(x^{2k-2}+y^{2k-2})|x-y|, \,\,\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R},$ by using a convexity argument. I would like to refer to the following, $$|\frac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}| = \int_0^1 e^{tx+(1-t)y}dt \leq\int_0^1(te^x + (1-t)e^y) dt = \frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^y), \,\,\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Given that $x^k$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ for only $k$ even, I do not know how to handle this. Can somebody provide a solution or some hints ? Thanks.

Comment: But in this inequality you only use the integral between $0$ and $1$ right? In this interval $x^k$ is always convex. So can't you just use the inequality and replace $e^x$ with $x^k$ accordingly?

Comment: Thanks. The integral bounds are related to the variable $t$ which we need in defining convexity.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right :D

Comment: You can still use your argument as I explained it in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar argument as the one you are referring to. The inequality you want to prove only has odd exponents on the left side and even exponents on the right side. So you can use the convexity of $x^k$ for even $k$ and the fact that $\frac d {dx} x^{2k-1} = (2k-1)x^{2k-2}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
|\frac{x^{2k-1}-y^{2k-1}}{x-y}|&=(2k-1)\int_0^1(tx+(1-t)y)^{2k-2}dt\\
&\leq(2k-1)\int_0^1(tx^{2k-2}+(1-t)y^{2k-2})dt \\
&=\frac {2k-1} 2(x^{2k-2}+y^{2k-2})
\end{align*}